# Substitutability in First-Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, substitution

Here is a definition for substitutability found in a PDF of logic notes by Eric Pacuit:

[image]

I am more concerned with the part of the definition squared in red. My question is: Given $(\forall y) \psi$, does this mean that, since $y$ does not occur free in $(\forall y) \psi$, is $\tau$ substitutable for $y$ in $(\forall y) \psi$?

Comment: Yes, because the term *substitutable* means that performing the operation we "cause no troubles". In that case, the operation is allowed simply because it does not change the original formula.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I found another definition for substitutability from the textbook by Arindama Singh: $y$ is free for $x$ in $\phi$ iff $x$ does not occur free within the scope of any $\forall y$ or $\exists y$. Is the negation: $y$ is not free for $x$ in $\phi$ iff $x$ occurs free within the scope of any $\forall y$ or $\exists y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the answer is yes, $\tau$ is substitutable for $y$ in $(\forall y)\phi$. This happens because there is nothing that to substitute and, therefore, you not change the original formula.